# MySQL AUTO DECREMENT instead of AUTO INCREMENT, is it possible?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I would like to have negative auto generated keys on a table.

Instead of Keys: 1,2,3,..,X
I would like Keys: -1,-2,-3,...,-X

I need this because I have to create a mirror table to use in UNION with the original and 'understand' which records come from the original table and which ones come from the mirror table.

Do you think this is a good idea?
Is there a simple way to get negative auto decremented key? Or do I have to use triggers?

Comment: Another way is to shift range by `id - MAX_INT` so you will get `-MAX_INT+1 .. 0` or simply prefix wiht `-`.

Comment: @lad2025 if I run `ALTER TABLE  ic_soggetti_aux AUTO_INCREMENT = - MAXINT` I get the error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-MAXINT' at line 2

Comment: Unfortunately you missed my point. I was thinking about `INSERT INTO table_x SELECT id, cola, colb FROM src UNION ALL SELECT -id, cola, cob FROM src` This way 1 will become -1 and so on. Alternatively instead of `-id` you could shift by max INT so `id - 2^32` so `1 -> -2^32+1` and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html says:

> - Assigning a negative value to the AUTO_INCREMENT column
>
>   In all lock modes (0, 1, and 2), the behavior of the auto-increment mechanism is not defined if you assign a negative value to the AUTO_INCREMENT column.

In other words, down that path lies chaos.

MySQL supports an option `auto_increment_increment` with which you can define how *much* to increment by each time you increment, but the value must be greater than 0.

```
mysql> set session auto_increment_increment = -1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                  |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect auto_increment_increment value: '-1' |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select @@auto_increment_increment;
+----------------------------+
| @@auto_increment_increment |
+----------------------------+
|                          1 |
+----------------------------+
```

You explained why you want to do this:

*I need this because I have to create a mirror table to use in UNION with the original and 'understand' which records come from the original table and which ones come from the mirror table.*

Use another column to indicate which table the rows came from:

```
SELECT 'original' AS WhichTable, column1, column2, column3 
FROM MyOriginalTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'mirror', column1, column2, column3 
FROM MyMirrorTable;
```